# Saving a image using bpy.ops.image.save()

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting

I need help in saving a color pass image of a recent rendered image. First I need to render the image using - bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) then I need to add soem filters in the final rendered image then save that as a color pass image. Basically need to call the bpy.ops.image.save() while running blender in background. Please let me know if this is achievable or not

Comment: What kind of "filters" you're talking about? Any custom filters or post effects using the compostor?

Comment: Im jsut changing the color management settings after rendering a image. Then want to save the color pass of it by connecting Renderlayer Diffcol to Composite image. Im able to achive this but unable to save the final image after these changes

Comment: You can do that beforehand and add mutliple output nodes for each pass. Ideally save to exr, linear by default.

Comment: 3d deisgners want me to do taht settings after getting the render. They want filmic for render and standard for color pass image